# the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty} (1+x)^{-1}e^{-x}dx$

Tags: calculus

I wish to calculate the improper integral
$\int_0^{\infty} (1+x)^{-1}e^{-x}dx$. How shoud we start? Give me some hint.

Comment: This integral requires [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)

Comment: This is known as the [Gompertz constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GompertzConstant.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a substitution $u = 1 + x$; this transforms the integral into

$$e \int_{1}^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{u} du = -e \, \text{Ei}(-1) \approx .596$$

where $\text{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), which cannot be written in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Does the integral converge in the usual sense?

Comment: @Yamamoto Yes, by comparison to the function $e^{-x}$, which is integrable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didin't know the exponential integral.